# Сбой на IPad [UIPopoverPresentationController presentationTransitionWillBegin]

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift3

Сбои идут только на IPad...Не пойму по какому поповеру??? Поповеров не использовал, только алерт, и то один до которого надо еще добраться через покупки, это не он. Еще при первом запуске алерт показывает на разрешение уведомлений
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: посмотрите текст голубым наверху ошибки. что то про UIActivityViewController

Comment: Пытался перевести, но не понял смысла(((

Comment: Надо выставить `sourceView` или `buttonItem`

Comment: Я извиняюсь, а как это делается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После добавления activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view код все равно будет крэшить. Необходимо добавлять sourceView И sourceRect, так что выставите activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = self.view.bounds
Но выставлять так это плохой тон. Система пытается понять, откуда в Popover рисовать якорь и вы должны ей помочь, указав правильную View.
Так же есть вариант использовать activityViewController.popoverPresentationController.barButtonItem
При его использовании, указывать sourceRect нет необходимости.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за подсказку, разобрался
добавил: activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view